# How to merge two differently multi-indexed dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index

I have two multi-indexed dataframes `df1` with three levels and `df2` with two. The indices resulted from `df1.groupby([col_1, col_2, col_3])` and `df2.groupby([col_1, col_2])`. `col_1` and `col_2` are the same in both dataframes, but, because of the third level in `df1` of different lenghts; `df1`has 2425 rows and `df2`783.

What I'm trying to do is to merge both dataframes so that `df2` gets spread up that the length of indices level 0 and 1 are of the same length in `df1`and `df2` so that the resulting dataframe is also of 2425 rows.

I used `df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)` but the resulting dataframe remains with only 2385 rows. 
I used `df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` but it raised a `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes`.

Is there an elegant way to solve this? I appreciate every help

EDIT: data sample

`df1:`

```
                                                                    Areaclccat1990  ...  Areaclccat2012
FID_Weser_Catchments_134_WQ_Stations_FINAL_LAEA... SNR1 gridcode_1                  ...                
0                                                  3152 1                 0.002764  ...        0.007248
                                                        2                 0.980105  ...        0.972941
                                                        3                 0.005049  ...        0.017166
                                                        4                 0.012082  ...        0.002645
                                                   3155 1                      NaN  ...        0.000003
                                                        2                 1.000000  ...        0.996788
                                                        3                      NaN  ...        0.003209
                                                   3255 1                      NaN  ...        0.058950
                                                        2                 0.989654  ...        0.941050
                                                        4                 0.010346  ...             NaN
                                                   5958 1                      NaN  ...        0.004463
                                                        2                 0.955098  ...        0.958452
                                                        3                 0.014408  ...        0.027835
                                                        4                 0.030494  ...        0.009250
                                                   5966 1                 0.007184  ...        0.011448
                                                        2                 0.955668  ...        0.949824
                                                        3                 0.037148  ...        0.038728
                                                   5970 1                      NaN  ...        0.001141
                                                        2                 0.979750  ...        0.930495
                                                        3                 0.011281  ...        0.068364
```

`df2:`

```
                                                          Areaclccat1990  ...  Areaclccat2012
FID_Weser_Catchments_134_WQ_Stations_FINAL_LAEA... SNR1                   ...                
0                                                  3152      1654.636456  ...     1550.415658
                                                   3155      1820.433231  ...     1758.125539
                                                   3255        43.056576  ...       39.436385
                                                   5958      2306.806057  ...     2120.791289
                                                   5966         7.444977  ...        5.763853
                                                   5970      3087.717009  ...     2615.253450
                                                   6435       240.342745  ...      255.033888
                                                   6534       647.293171  ...      621.116222
                                                   6535      9929.136397  ...     9653.021903
                                                   6611       947.912232  ...      754.783147
                                                   6631     13528.073523  ...    13545.356498
                                                   6632     14023.097062  ...    13897.394309
                                                   6633      5913.895620  ...     5398.585720
                                                   6634     17463.795952  ...    17159.138628
                                                   6635     10791.618411  ...    10306.725199
                                                   6636      9664.138661  ...     9742.442935
                                                   9473       131.268559  ...      128.477078
                                                   9672       107.831005  ...      102.464959
                                                   9673        13.044806  ...       29.566828
                                                   16051      443.810802  ...      428.493495
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coonvert third level to column before `merge` with `how='left'` for left join:

```
df3 = df1.reset_index(level=2).merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

Comment: I tried but it's basically the same as what happens with ```df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)```, only 2385 rows remain but with the additional column of level 2

Comment: @Benno_Banton - Can you add some data sample?

Comment: I added the first 20 entries

Comment: @Benno_Banton - Can you check answer if add `how='left'` ?